# How to sort an R Plotly grouped bar chart within groups?

Tags: r, r-plotly

Reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

df <- data.table(
  x = c(rep("positive", 4), rep("neutral", 4), rep("none", 4), rep("negative", 4)),
  y = rep(c("one", "two", "three", "four"), 4),
  percent = c(
    38.9, 33.3, 8.7, 19.1, 29.4, 29.6, 21.6, 19.4,
    37.4, 24.9, 16.6, 21.1, 27.8, 34.5, 14.4, 23.2
  )
)

# Sort rows based on 'percent' within each subgroup in 'y', preserving grouping in 'x'
df <- df[order(x, -percent)]

plot_ly(
  df, 
  x = ~percent,
  y = ~x,
  color = ~y,
  type = "bar",
  orientation = "h",
  hovertemplate = "Group: %{fullData.name} <br> Percent: %{x}% <extra></extra>",
  opacity = 0.9,
  hoverlabel = list(
    align = "left"
  )
) %>%
  layout(
    font = list(
      family = "Open Sans",
      size = 13
    ),
    xaxis = list(
      title = "", 
      showticklabels = TRUE
    ),
    yaxis = list(
      title = ""
    )
  )
```

This produces the following chart:

[image]

How do I sort the bars from highest to lowest (percentages) within each group? Is this possible at the R level? I tried specifying [categoryorder and categoryarray](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/yaxis/) parameters in `layout` but it doesn't seem to take effect? Thanks.

Comment: I actually don't think this functionality exists in R's version of plotly. You might be able to accomplish it with faceted subplots.

Comment: Could try `plotly::ggplotly()` with `tidytext::reorder_within()` in a `ggplot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I would do for a faceted solution which uses `ggcharts` library and `bar_chart`:

```
p <- ggcharts::bar_chart(
  df,
  y,
  percent,
  fill = x,
  facet = x,
)
p
```

[image: Not exactly what you wanted]

Comment: I like this. I'll mess around with `ggcharts` a bit. Although it is not interactive, I may be able to combine it with `ggplotly()`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you were looking for interactive, but that makes sense seeing as you are using plotly. I've never tried ggplotly myself, if you find the answer using that, please post it as an answer. I would love to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal solution based on Andrew Ingalls' solution and Dan Adams' suggestion in the comment:

```
library(ggcharts)
ggcharts::bar_chart(
    df,
    y,
    percent,
    fill = x,
    facet = x,
  ) |>
    plotly::ggplotly()
```

Also tested with `plotly::renderPlotly()`.